# Import unknown text polygon format to QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, polygon, csv, json

I'm trying to visualize this park in the DRC.
Thinking it was a WKT polygon, I isolated one shape as a test and saved it as a CSV.

*Here*

```json
{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":27,"NOM":"Parc de la N'Sele","ET_ID":24,"ProtectedArea":"Protected Area","ProtectedArea_FR":"Zone protégée","Shape__Area":73354366.0905762,"Shape__Length":48296.2609999999},"geometry":{"rings":[[[17303,10959],[0,6],[6,0],[0,6],[6,0],[0,6],[6,0],[6,0],[0,6],[6,0],[6,0],[0,6],[6,0],[6,0],[0,6],[6,0],[0,6],[0,6],[-6,0],[0,6],[0,7],[-6,0],[0,6],[-6,0],[0,6],[0,6],[-6,0],[-6,0],[0,-6],[-6,0],[-6,0],[0,-6],[-6,0],[0,-6],[0,-7],[-6,0],[0,-6],[0,-6],[-6,0],[0,-6],[0,-6],[-6,0],[0,-6],[-7,0],[0,-6],[-5,0],[0,-6],[0,-6],[0,-6],[5,0],[7,0],[6,0],[6,0]]]}}
```

I'm realizing I'm dealing with a totally different format as my previous WKT polygons. So here is the original JSON. Again I isolated one shape from the JSON.

*Here* - the same shape with the extra stuff I removed before

```json
{
    "objectIdFieldName": "OBJECTID",
    "uniqueIdField": {
        "name": "OBJECTID",
        "isSystemMaintained": true
    },
    "globalIdFieldName": "",
    "geometryProperties": {
        "shapeAreaFieldName": "Shape__Area",
        "shapeLengthFieldName": "Shape__Length",
        "units": "esriMeters"
    },
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 102100,
        "latestWkid": 3857
    },
    "transform": {
        "originPosition": "upperLeft",
        "scale": [152.87405657041103, 152.87405657041103],
        "translate": [-938237.77120000124, 1197112.0909000002]
    },
    "fields": [{
        "name": "OBJECTID",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
        "alias": "OBJECTID",
        "sqlType": "sqlTypeOther",
        "domain": null,
        "defaultValue": null
    }, {
        "name": "NOM",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
        "alias": "NOM",
        "sqlType": "sqlTypeOther",
        "length": 40,
        "domain": null,
        "defaultValue": null
    }, {
        "name": "ET_ID",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeInteger",
        "alias": "ET_ID",
        "sqlType": "sqlTypeOther",
        "domain": null,
        "defaultValue": null
    }, {
        "name": "ProtectedArea",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
        "alias": "ProtectedArea",
        "sqlType": "sqlTypeOther",
        "length": 20,
        "domain": null,
        "defaultValue": null
    }, {
        "name": "ProtectedArea_FR",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
        "alias": "ProtectedArea_FR",
        "sqlType": "sqlTypeOther",
        "length": 50,
        "domain": null,
        "defaultValue": null
    }, {
        "name": "Shape__Area",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
        "alias": "Shape__Area",
        "sqlType": "sqlTypeDouble",
        "domain": null,
        "defaultValue": null
    }, {
        "name": "Shape__Length",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
        "alias": "Shape__Length",
        "sqlType": "sqlTypeDouble",
        "domain": null,
        "defaultValue": null
    }],
    "features": [{
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 27,
            "NOM": "Parc de la N'Sele",
            "ET_ID": 24,
            "ProtectedArea": "Protected Area",
            "ProtectedArea_FR": "Zone protégée",
            "Shape__Area": 73354366.0905762,
            "Shape__Length": 48296.2609999999
        },
        "geometry": {
            "rings": [
                [
                    [17303, 10959],
                    [0, 6],
                    [6, 0],
                    [0, 6],
                    [6, 0],
                    [0, 6],
                    [6, 0],
                    [6, 0],
                    [0, 6],
                    [6, 0],
                    [6, 0],
                    [0, 6],
                    [6, 0],
                    [6, 0],
                    [0, 6],
                    [6, 0],
                    [0, 6],
                    [0, 6],
                    [-6, 0],
                    [0, 6],
                    [0, 7],
                    [-6, 0],
                    [0, 6],
                    [-6, 0],
                    [0, 6],
                    [0, 6],
                    [-6, 0],
                    [-6, 0],
                    [0, -6],
                    [-6, 0],
                    [-6, 0],
                    [0, -6],
                    [-6, 0],
                    [0, -6],
                    [0, -7],
                    [-6, 0],
                    [0, -6],
                    [0, -6],
                    [-6, 0],
                    [0, -6],
                    [0, -6],
                    [-6, 0],
                    [0, -6],
                    [-7, 0],
                    [0, -6],
                    [-5, 0],
                    [0, -6],
                    [0, -6],
                    [0, -6],
                    [5, 0],
                    [7, 0],
                    [6, 0],
                    [6, 0]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

I'm presuming I need to reformat this to get it into QGIS(?).

Comment: all csv content is just that? ? or is there another parts?

Comment: It looks like someone tried to export a geojson out of ArcGIS but the formatting does not look correct.  It lists rings as the geometry which is not a valid type for a geojson.  https://geojson.org/

Comment: Your snippet is an `esrijson` feature.  I can't say anything more unless you  provide more details, at least a couple of lines, including the header.

Comment: Do you know what its coordinate system (CRS) is?

Comment: Because of a previous data set, I presumed I was working with a CSV polygon format so I extracted this data from a JSON. I'm new to StackExchange should I add the JSON to my original question as an edit?

Comment: Absolutely. It helps us understand your problem better.

Comment: Do you have other data with different geometry? Line, point etc

Answer (score 15):

Interesting. It is obviously not a CSV content, but a JSON.

If you use the following script to convert the file content to a layer in QGIS Python Editor, you get a polygon as in the image.

**Edit**: OK. This is a primitive script for data you have, whose geometry type is polygon. Coordinates are relative to the first position (`[17303, 10959]`) and you also have to use `transform` and `scale` parameters.

```py
import json

file_path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/file.csv"
with open(file_path) as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)

crs = data["spatialReference"]["latestWkid"]

# new memory layer
uri = f"Polygon?crs=EPSG:{crs}"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Layer", "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()

# create fields
field_types = {"esriFieldTypeOID": QVariant.Int,
               "esriFieldTypeInteger": QVariant.Int,
               "esriFieldTypeDouble": QVariant.Double,
               "esriFieldTypeString": QVariant.String}

for field in data["fields"]:
    field_name = field["name"]
    field_type = field_types[field["type"]]
    field_length = field["length"] if field_type==QVariant.String else 10
    pr.addAttributes([QgsField(field_name, field_type, len=field_length)])
layer.updateFields()

x_translate = data["transform"]["translate"][0]
y_translate = data["transform"]["translate"][1]
x_scale = data["transform"]["scale"][0]
y_scale = data["transform"]["scale"][1]

for feature in data["features"]:
    new_feature = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
    
    for attribute, value in feature["attributes"].items():
        new_feature[attribute] = value
    
    points = feature["geometry"]["rings"][0]
    x_world = points[0][0] * x_scale + x_translate
    y_world = y_translate - points[0][1] * y_scale
    
    ps = [QgsPointXY(x_world, y_world)]
    for p in points[1:]:
        x_world += p[0] * x_scale
        y_world += p[1] * y_scale
        ps.append(QgsPointXY(x_world, y_world))
        
    geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([ps])
    new_feature.setGeometry(geom)
    pr.addFeatures([new_feature])
    
layer.updateExtents()
    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

First, the syntax of your data is [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). But it's not the common [GeoJSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) representation, which would be easy to work with. It looks a bit like [ESRI JSON](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/common-data-types/feature-object.htm), which uses `"attributes"` and `"rings"`. But the ESRI JSON examples I've seen store *absolute* coordinates. It seems highly probable here that all the coordinates past the `17303,10959` are *relative* to that first position. If you add each coordinate pair on to that, it makes the shape below, finishing back at the starting `17303,10959`. Is that about the shape you expected to see?

[image: Line plot of coordinates from the question making a lumpy blue shape]

It may be distorted, reversed or rotated, depending on the original Coordinate Reference System used to define it. Finding that Coordinate Reference System is still essential to accurately finding where this is, even given that you know its approximate position.

1. Were there any other columns in the CSV?
2. Were there any other files with the CSV, especially with the same name but a different extension? These could help to place it.

Answer (score 2):

I adjusted the above python script. Fliping the X/Y_world axis so it has the correct projection. I also added an if function in case of empty shapes. Here is the updated script. It works brilliantly.

```
import json
from qgis.core import (
    QgsVectorLayer,
    QgsField,
    QgsFeature,
    QgsPointXY,
    QgsGeometry,
    QgsProject
)
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

file_path = "C:/Users/j/Desktop/LD_DRC_MAP/DRC_SCRAPE/admin_protected-areas.json"
with open(file_path) as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)

crs = data["spatialReference"]["latestWkid"]

# new memory layer
uri = f"Polygon?crs=EPSG:{crs}"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Layer", "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()

# create fields
field_types = {"esriFieldTypeOID": QVariant.Int,
               "esriFieldTypeDate": QVariant.Double,
               "esriFieldTypeInteger": QVariant.Int,
               "esriFieldTypeDouble": QVariant.Double,
               "esriFieldTypeString": QVariant.String}

for field in data["fields"]:
    field_name = field["name"]
    field_type = field_types[field["type"]]
    field_length = field["length"] if field_type==QVariant.String else 10
    pr.addAttributes([QgsField(field_name, field_type, len=field_length)])
layer.updateFields()

x_translate = data["transform"]["translate"][0]
y_translate = data["transform"]["translate"][1]
x_scale = data["transform"]["scale"][0]
y_scale = data["transform"]["scale"][1]

for feature in data["features"]:
    new_feature = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
    
    for attribute, value in feature["attributes"].items():
        new_feature[attribute] = value
    
    if feature["geometry"]["rings"]:
        points = feature["geometry"]["rings"][0]
        x_world = points[0][0] * x_scale + x_translate
        y_world = y_translate - points[0][1] * y_scale
        
        ps = [QgsPointXY(x_world, y_world)]
        for p in points[1:]:
            x_world += p[0] * x_scale
            y_world -= p[1] * y_scale
            ps.append(QgsPointXY(x_world, y_world))
            
        geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([ps])
        new_feature.setGeometry(geom)
        pr.addFeatures([new_feature])
    
layer.updateExtents()
    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```